# text with dot displayed as hyperlink

Tags: android, hyperlink

I am having a edit text which is behaving like feeds in face book. So whenever i post something like "www.google.com" it is showing as hyperlink, But at the same time whenever i post something like "abcd.abcd" , it is also showing me as a hyper link. I want to show my post as link only when i add "http" or "www" , How to achieve this. Thanks in advance

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/etFeedsText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:maxLength="2000"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25.8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8.3dp"
                android:hint="@string/enter_your_post"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                android:textColor="@color/feeds_text"
                android:textSize="13.3sp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare your text & can find out if its a valid URL or not by this method,

```
/** 
* This is used to check the given URL is valid or not.
* @param url
* @return true if url is valid, false otherwise.
*/
private boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
    Pattern p = Patterns.WEB_URL;
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url.toLowerCase());
    return m.matches();
}
```

If the text is not an URL then remove the underline from bottom like,

```
if(!isValidUrl(yourUrl)){
   stripUnderlines(TextView textView)
}


private void stripUnderlines(TextView textView) {
        Spannable s = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
        URLSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class);
        for (URLSpan span: spans) {
            int start = s.getSpanStart(span);
            int end = s.getSpanEnd(span);
            s.removeSpan(span);
            span = new URLSpanNoUnderline(span.getURL());
            s.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
        }
        textView.setText(s);
    }
```

It requires a customized version of URLSpan which doesn't enable the TextPaint's "underline" property:

```
private class URLSpanNoUnderline extends URLSpan {
        public URLSpanNoUnderline(String url) {
            super(url);
        }
        @Override public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: hey thanks wilson. I will try and let you know. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your Edittext

```
Linkify.addLinks(etFeedsText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

This will consider only valid URLs.
Also you can use a textview, if you are just displaying the data. Edittext is not necessary.